# How to run a paste-function within a for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, data-cleaning, paste

I have a dataset where I need to calculate a sum-variable of multiple variables.
I created a for-loop to perform this one variable at a time:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$Q1[i] = sum(df$Q1_A[i], df$Q1_B[i], df$Q1_C[i], na.rm = T)
}
```

Is there a way to do this for all variables (Q1:Q60) at once?
Basically I need a function that adjusts the variable-number from 1 to 2 to 3 to ... to 60.
Do I need a for-loop within a for-loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.